# Sails 0.9.4, socket.io, newbie

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

Just getting started with Sails & Socket.io.  I'm following the docs and setup a simple test project here:

https://github.com/timfulmer/sails-sockets

According to the Sails docs, http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/sockets, socket subscriptions are setup on the first socket call:

> socket.get(), socket.post(), etc. are methods available in the client-side SDK included in new Sails projects. In this example, we'll use them to talk to the backend via Socket.io. Please be aware that you can use these methods whether or not you're using CRUD blueprints.

The test project defines a quick model/controller, with CRUD methods.  It connects to the socket using `socket.get`, and receives previously posted model instances correctly.

Posting a new instance using `socket.post` makes it to the Sails server and creates the new instance.  However, the new instance is never sent to the connection created with `socket.get`.  Even when running the page in two different browser tabs.

Also, posting using a GET request from the browser hangs and never returns.

Am I reading the docs incorrectly or making some other newb mistake?

Thanks,

-- Tim

Comment: you haven't committed any code to your repo. > However, the new instance is never sent to the connection created with socket.get. do you mean the live updating? that comes back using `socket.on('message', function(data))`

Comment: Bummer about the rep, I voted you up for the empty repo comment :)  Code has been pushed, sorry about that.  There is a `socket.on` call made in `assets/js/app.js`, part of the default sails generated stubs.  Seems like that one should work, but it is not.

Comment: Try removing everything in your controller. So that you are just exporting an empty obj. Let Sails blueprints do the work when just getting started.
- Also -
until you request the model, you wont be subscribed to it. try having the client `get('/socketupdate')` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turned out to be a total newbie error.  Sails does not magically call the function passed into `socket.get` when new messages are emitted.  Sails is magic, but not that magic.  Turns out one must implement what to do with new messages in `assets/js/app.js`.  Problem between chair and keyboard, sails rocks!

**EDIT**

Updated the sample project to work with Sails.js + Socket.io + Backbone.js + CORS, with Backbone.js frontend hosted separately (in s3) than the Sails.js backend:

https://github.com/timfulmer/sails-sockets

Lots of little gotchas involved.